# InvalidArgumentException Please provide a valid cache path

Tags: php, laravel

As this question has been asked soo many time and the solution is clear, but my problem is I have done every possible solution but it still doesn't solve my error.

I have all the required folders

```
-storage
   -app
   -framework
      -cache 
      -session
      -testing
      -views
   -logs
```

and also all the ".gitignore" files as well
also have run permission command

Below is my config/view.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Compiled View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines where all the compiled Blade templates will be
    | stored for your application. Typically, this is within the storage
    | directory. However, as usual, you are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        realpath(storage_path('/storage/framework/views'))
    ),

];
```

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:clear` and also can you share your `config/view.php`? You also need to have a `storage/framework/views` folder as well (it's not clear here that you do)

Comment: non of the php artisan command is working every command is showing the same error "cache path". I have all the required folders.

Comment: Check your code you might be trying to compile a view before all necessary service providers have ran.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have that issue !!